# Error while tagging friends from facebook using fb sdk

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=10 "The user navigated away from
>   the Facebook app prior to completing this AppCall. This AppCall is now
>   cancelled and needs to be retried to get a successful completion"
>   UserInfo=0x1815f150 {NSLocalizedDescription=The user navigated away
>   from the Facebook app prior to completing this AppCall. This AppCall
>   is now cancelled and needs to be retried to get a successful
>   completion, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The user navigated away from the
>   Facebook app prior to completing this AppCall. This AppCall is now
>   cancelled and needs to be retried to get a successful completion}

Comment: Here is my code:                                                                  FBLinkShareParams *params = [[FBLinkShareParams alloc] init]; params.link = sharableLin;    params.friends = selectedFriendsUidsArray; [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams:params    clientState:nil                                                                                               handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {}];

Answer (score 0):

You receive an error `FBErrorAppActivatedWhilePendingAppCall`. If you follow the facebook guidelines and call `[FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActive]` when `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` is occured and you presented this dialog before this notification, then the dialog will be interrupted with this kind of an error.

Facebook auth with ios app switching an application to background and the app is not foreground when you receive session state change through `[FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:]`. You should not show the dialog right after the session state is open.
You should ensure that `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive` before starting a dialog. If it's not - make a bool flag that you need to show a dialog and call it in `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`.